# Spring MVC: (If is possible) search form on submit event generate a URI instead of URL pattern format

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, spring-web

I have a `@Controller` with the following `@RequestMapping` annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value={"somevalue"}, 
                method=RequestMethod.GET,
                produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String findOneById(@PathVariable String id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute(findOneById(id));
    return "some view";
}
```

Observe it uses `@PathVariable`, based on URI, it works around `/persons/{id}`, for example for:

- /persons/100
- /persons/200

it retrieves an expected person.

that `@RequestMapping` method works fine when:

- I put the URL/URI in the same Web Browser address bar (.../persons/200)
- when I generate a report of items including for each one a link to see the details (.../persons/200).

I am trying to create a search form such as follows:

```
<body>

        <spring:url var="findOne" value="/persons/" >

        </spring:url>

        <form action="${findOne}" method="get">     
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="id"><spring:message code="persona.id.label"/></label></td>
                    <td><input name="id" id="id" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="search"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
```

My problem is, when I press submit the form always generates/creates the URL to do the search in the format `/persons?id=100`. I know it is normal and is expected.

But just being curious and of course *if is possible*:

**Question:**

What would be the new configuration to generate a URI pattern such as `/persons/100` instead of `/persons?id=100` when I press the submit button?

I want avoid create a new `@RequestMapping` method working around with a `@RequestParam` (it for `?id=100`). It to complement the `@RequesMapping` method working with `@PathVariable` (it for `/100`) version.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript to handle the form submission.